# amazing bug in code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, swing, arraylist

Helo. I have two arraylist's:

```
public static ArrayList<Shop> shops;
```

with field:    `public static double dist;`

and the second arraylist: `public static ArrayList<Double> for_sort_shops;`

I also have a code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < shops.size(); i++) {
    Log.i("palval", "for_sort_shops.get(i) = "
            + for_sort_shops.get(i));
}

for (int i = 0; i < shops.size(); i++) {
    shops.get(i).dist = for_sort_shops.get(i);
}

Log.i("palval", "---------------------------------------");
for (int i = 0; i < shops.size(); i++) {
    Log.i("palval", "shops.get(i).dist = "
            + shops.get(i).dist);
}
```

And what result I've get?

[image]

How it's possible?!
Help me to understand.

Comment: Remove the word `static` from `public static double dist;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You declared `dist` static, which means that it's value is defined at class level and shared among all instances. in your program you only see the last value assigned to it.

Answer (score 3):

Your field is

```
public static double dist
```

Because it's `static`, there's only one `dist` value for the entire `Shops` class.

You need to make this value non-`static` for each `Shop` to have it's own `dist` value.

Answer (score 2):

Since your field `public static double dist;` is static, there is only one of those throughout the execution of your code. So you are updating the same variable over and over again. Take off the `static` off of dist to achieve your desired results.